# Symfony 3: Handling exception MethodNotAllowedException

Tags: php, symfony, http, post, get

I've not clear how handling the exception MethodNotAllowedException in Symfony.
Let me explain,

### ON VIEW

Suppose that we written this script on View to go to the Controller:

```
//Script on view to go to the controller
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "{{ path('my_path') }}",
      data: { myValue }
    }).done(function( data ) {
        //do something
    });
</script>
```

### Define the route

We define the sending of data using the post method. Now, see it the route in **routing.yml**

```
//scr/myBundle/Resources/routing.yml
my_path:
    path:     /my-path
    defaults: { _controller: myBundle:myMain:doAndReturnSomething }
    methods:  [POST]
```

### Working on Controller

Now, in controller

```
//scr/myBundle/Resources/Controller/myMainController
class myMainController extends Controller{
  public function doAndReturnSomethingAction()
  {
    //doSomeThing
    return  $this->render('myBundle:myViews:view.html.twig');
}
```

This works great. How we can see, the method defined to do the send is POST.

Now, when we reload the page with the browser or press f5. All works fine. 
But, if we press enter in the url on browser

```
//Click on: localhost/myAplicationDir/web/my-path
```

The aplication get broken, sure by we don't define sending with GET, I suppose.

How can I get this exception in Symfony and show the user a custom page?

I'm thinking in redirect to myBundle index page. Any sugest?

Thanks for help.
I'm just starting with PHP and Symfony.

### SOLUTION

### Solution #1

Create two separate routers with GET and POST methods respectively

### Solution #2

I wouldn't like created two separate routes. My controller has many methods.
I wouldn't like send the data via GET by URL. But I wouldn't like that my application get broken.

```
//scr/myBundle/Resources/routing.yml
my_path:
    path:     /my-path
    defaults: { _controller: myBundle:myMain:doAndReturnSomething }
    methods:  [POST, GET]


//scr/myBundle/Resources/Controller/myMainController
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
class myMainController extends Controller{
  public function doAndReturnSomethingAction(Request $request)
  {
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
      //doSomeThing
    else
      //redirect to index


    //This can be other way
    //myValue is sending via POST
    if ($request->get('myValue') != null)
      //doSomething
    else
      //redirect to index

    //return  $this->render('myBundle:myViews:view.html.twig');
}
```

It's there any method for correct this in all routes on routing.yml??

Comment: If t this a `POST` and a `GET` route why don't just add it to the `methods` key in the `routing.yml`?

Comment: One could even make a route/function for both post and get separately if required.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to enable `GET` on the route for this to work as you're intending.

```
//scr/myBundle/Resources/routing.yml
my_path:
    path:     /my-path
    defaults: { _controller: myBundle:myMain:doAndReturnSomething }
    methods:  [POST, GET]
```

Although I wouldn't necessarily recommend this, and would instead recommend having two separate routes, and if absolutely necessary redirecting the `GET` from `doAndReturnSomething` to a separate Controller. Essentially ending up with `doSomethingAction` and `returnSomethingAction` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for you help, it's very usefull